# 'Element is no longer attached to the DOM' after drop down selection refreshes the page

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium

I'm writing a Selenium unittest which selects an option from a dropdown menu triggering a page refresh (not a full refresh, but JS changes the DOM) to show data based on that selection. My testcase can be seen [here on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PF1r8hBT)

So after the data is reloaded selenium can't find the further options to loop through. I don't actually need to loop through anymore though.
I could just do an xpath lookup to see if `option.text` is in the H2 element of the page but my attempt failed...

```
for option in dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if self.ff.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[contains(text(), option.text)"):
        pass    # Employee Selected
```

From the following code could anyone help avoid this 'attached to DOM' error? Essentially if I could select option[1] or something and then just carry on with the rest of the test that'd be ideal.

```
dropdown = self.ff.find_element_by_id('employeeDatabaseSelect')
for option in dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    try:
        option.click()  # causes JS refresh which you need to wait for
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Exception ', e
else: sys.exit("Error: There are no employees for this employer")
print 'Dropdown: ', dropdown.getText()
WebDriverWait(self.ff, 50).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[contains(text(), dropdown.getText())"))
```

My stacktrace looks like this;

```
 [exec] test_process (__main__.viewEmployeeUseCase) ...
 [exec] ERROR
 [exec]
 [exec] ===============================================================
 [exec] ERROR: test_process (__main__.viewEmployeeUseCase)
 [exec] ---------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] Traceback (most recent call last):
 [exec]   File "viewEmployeeUnitTest.py", line 43, in test_process
 [exec]     print 'Dropdown: ', dropdown.getText()
 [exec] AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getText'
 [exec]
 [exec] ---------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] Ran 1 test in 16.063s
 [exec]
 [exec] FAILED (errors=1)
 [exec] Exception  Message: u'Element is no longer attached to the DOM'
 [exec] Exception  Message: u'Element is no longer attached to the DOM'
 [exec] Exception  Message: u'Element is no longer attached to the DOM'
 [exec] Exception  Message: u'Element is no longer attached to the DOM'
 [exec] Exception  Message: u'Element is no longer attached to the DOM'
 [exec] Exception  Message: u'Element is no longer attached to the DOM'
 [exec] Exception  Message: u'Element is no longer attached to the DOM'
 [exec] Dropdown:  Tearing Down!
```

That final `Tearing Down!` is the comment printed from my tearDown() function.

Answer (score 2):

As you have seen refreshing the page can cause strange behaviors with element references. Another common error you'll see is the stale element exception.

From the stacktrace I would try to modify the second to last line to:

```
print 'Dropdown: ', self.ff.find_element_by_id('employeeDatabaseSelect').getText()
```

This way you have a fresh reference to the element.

Similarly another area that can be causing problems is the line:

```
for option in dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
```

If the page is refreshed between iterations, `dropdown` might no longer be valid. If this is the case, I would try this:

1. Go through all the options and keep a list of their values/text
2. Go through the list of values/text (not elements) and then find the option element that matches it

Again, this is so you use a fresh reference of `dropdown` every time.

Comment: You've helped me make sense of this :) by looking up the drop down from self.ff every time it still produced the same error so I'd rather just interact with 1 option because I only need to ensure the list is selected. I don't need to go through each in the list. How could I break out of the for loop after the first click?

Comment: If you only want to check the first one, you don't need the loop anymore. You might just want to try  `dropdown.find_element_by_tag_name('option').click()`

Comment: Ah yes. That should of been obvious but I think I've just been looking at that loop for too long! Thanks!